# Using Jest to test React Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I am totally new in testing. Now I'm trying to test react routre.
How to test it correctly?
**Register.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import user from "./user";
import employee from "./employee";

const Registers = ({ match }) => (
  <div className="dashboard-wrapper">
    <Switch>
      <Redirect exact from={`${match.url}/`} to={`${match.url}/user`} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}/user`} component={user} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}/employee`} component={employee} />
      <Redirect to="/error" />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
export default Registers;
```

**Tryed to test in this way.**

```
   Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
    test('invalid path should redirect to 404', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
     <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ '/user' ]}>
       <Registers/>
     </MemoryRouter>
   );
  expect(wrapper.find(user)).toHaveLength(0);
  expect(wrapper.find(employee)).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to wrap your Switch statement with Browser Router
- Second You need To mock Browser Router.

Mock Browser Router at path

```
" __mocks__/react-router-dom.js "

import React from 'react';
const rrd = require('react-router-dom');
// Just render plain div with its children
rrd.BrowserRouter = ({children}) => <div>{children}</div>
module.exports = rrd;
```

Test like

```
test('invalid path should redirect to 404', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ '/user' ]}>
      <App/>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
  expect(wrapper.find(user)).toHaveLength(0);
  expect(wrapper.find(employee)).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how and why to Mock Browser Router, please.
 Didn't understand that part

Comment: This is why https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter

Comment: I created a folder named `react-router-dom.js` and pass contend like you suggest.
Now getting error. 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` 
Error throws here ` from={`${match.url}/`}` 
Solved by adding this in test. `<Registers match={{url:""}}/>` 
Is this correct solution?

Comment: i think in your test file you need to mock whatever you're testing.
jest.mock()

Comment: Found article like your suggest. But can't understand `jest.mock('firebase/app');` what is doing this.
I think something like this I missed.

https://medium.com/@antonybudianto/react-router-testing-with-jest-and-enzyme-17294fefd303

Comment: search for react mock. This line is lo0king a firebase app environment.

Comment: But test is passed even if delete `react-router-dom.js` file. Why?

Comment: You've wrapped Routes with Browser Router or not  ? 
And deleted react-router-dom.js

Comment: Yes I did in this way.
`import { BrowserRouter as Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom" `

Comment: As per the medium article

We need to mock it because it’ll overlap with our MemoryRouter and causing the initialEntries not working.

Comment: Tryed to mock like this `jest.mock('./index', () => <users/>)` and get this error  `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`